# How to make a link within a TeX file into a page of an existing PDF file

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, pdf

Suppose there is a large online textbook in PDF, without TeX source code. How do I link to a certain page of it within my PDFLaTeX document?

Comment: Do you mean citing stuff?

Comment: I suspect he means something like `hyperref`, except cross-document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe has specified a syntax to open PDF files with some parameters inside URLs, see [Parameters for Opening PDF files](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf).

With package `hyperref`, your PDF document can refer to other PDF documents.
For example, the external document should be opened at page 4:

```
\url{http://www.example.com/foo.pdf?page=4}
\href{http://www.example.com/foo.pdf?page=4}{\nolinkurl{foo.pdf}, page 4}
```

However, all party members have to support this:

- The options should go into the link in the PDF file, done by package `hyperref`.
- The PDF viewer.
- The web browser, if the PDF is viewed there, and its PDF viewing component (browser itself, plugin, ...).